# android app add functionality to like fb page and comment on fb posts

Tags: android, button, facebook-like

Hello this is the first time I am integrating facebook in any of my android applications 
I need to implement functionality to like a fp page/post and comment on fb page/post ,,,!!
i have downloaded the fb sdk for android and played around with it how ever i am still not clear as to what to i need to do and how to approach the requirement 
What i need is when the user clicks a button in my app it automatically likes a fb post 
and it submits text from edit text as a comment to as fb post ,,!!
Can some one tell  how to go about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *"like"* a post:

Something like:

```
Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook();
mFacebook.request(THE_POST_ID + "/likes", parameters, "POST");
```

To *"comment"* on a post:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", edtComment.getText().toString());
mFacebook.request(THE_POST_ID + "/comments", parameters, "POST");
```

Comment: Facebook() is deprecated and this will not work. Any idea how its done in the new SDK?

Comment: @Andy: It is deprecated. Agreed. But it still works just fine. The SDK is still backward compatible. They even have an example in the SDK that uses the old methods. And this code is production code by the way. In an app available on the Google Play store.

Answer (score 0):

To like a post

```
Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), postId + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

                 @Override
                 public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                     this.like.setText("liked");
                     this.like.setEnabled(false);
                     CommentAdapter.this.like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.disabled_like);
                     this.getLikesCount();
                 }
            });
            Request.executeBatchAsync(likeRequest);
```